# I am trying to return array from rpc server(function returns address of local variable -wreturn-local-addr)

Tags: rpc

## include "array.h"

int *
forloop_1_svc(input *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    int result[argp->a];

```
printf("Server started********\n");

for (int i = 1; i < (argp->a); ++i)

{
    result[i]=i;
}


return result;
```

}